# android: how to save hash table values in shared preferences

Tags: android

I am new to java and android. I want to create hash table that takes a username and password and then saves that username and password in my phone cache using shared preferences.

Comment: Post what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok try this it ll help you in this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Hashtable<String, String> table;
SharedPreferences pref;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
    table = new Hashtable<>();
    table.put("r", "rohit");
    table.put("a", "anita");
    Log.e("table size", ""+table.size());
    Editor edit = pref.edit();
    edit.putString("hashdata", table.get("r"));
    edit.commit();

    Log.e("save hash data in pref", ""+pref.getString("hashdata", ""));


}
```

Comment: Just do what k0sh suggested. You don't need the hashtable (map) and just store key/value pairs in the preferences. If you really need the hashmap later in the program, you can still use it but for persisting in preferences, just keep it simple. BTW, I am not sure what kind of application is this. Generally storing password in clear text anywhere is not a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("username", "the user name ");   
editor.putString("password", "the user passowrd");  

editor.commit();
```

Btw storing the password in sharedpreferences is just a good idea for me to create an application that pull ur data and voilà get all your users passwords. You do not need to store the password in the device not by database and not by sharedpreferences.

Comment: @user3605640 we could make you the same question